# dfコマンドで出力したサイズを超えたduの計算結果の原因を求める

Tags: linux, filesystems

Linuxで下記のような事象に遭遇しました。ご存じの方は教えて欲しいです。

#### 事象

`df -h` コマンドでマウントしているボリュームが50GBのサイズを有している

`du -h` コマンドでマウントしているディレクトリの総サイズを調べてみたら、59GBでした。

#### 質問1

何故duで計算した結果はボリュームのサイズを超えたか？

#### 質問2

この二つのコマンドの計算が違うか？

#### 試したこと

- duのハードリンク、シンボルリンクと辿らないようなオプションを付ける
- findコマンドでtypeがfの全部を探して、duで個々のサイズを計算し、総量を出す

#### 想像した原因

1. ハードリンク、シンボルリンクが数回duによって計算された
   →　findでファイルだけ出して計算しても同じなので、関係なさそう
2. 該当ディレクトリのしたにまたは別のボリュームがマウントしている
   →　なかった
3. Windowsのような、ファイルを圧縮して保存という機能が有効
   →　不明

Comment: [duはファイルサイズではなくブロックサイズを表示する](https://www.greptips.com/posts/1158/)ので実際のサイズより大きく見えるようです。または[削除したファイルをつかんでいる](https://www.greptips.com/posts/1158/)ために容量オーバーしたままの例もあるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ブロックサイズとはいいますが、上限を超えることはできますか？
削除したファイルであれば、容量オーバーする前、クリアされると考えています。

Comment: 対象のファイルシステム内に sparce file があって、かつ、`du` コマンドで `-b` オプションを使用している場合に `du` による集計の方が `df` での結果よりも大きくなる事は可能性としてはあり得るかと思います。

Comment: 可能であればそれぞれの実行結果も質問に含めておくと、回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: ハードリンクの機能を誤解されている点と、シンボルリンクではなくシンボリックリンクです。

Answer (score 0):

思いつくのはこれくらいですね。

1. オープンしたまま削除されたファイルが存在している。
   `lsof /path/to/mount/point |grep '(deleted)$`
2. 拡張属性 (SELinux ラベルも含む) が大量に付与されているファイルが多数存在する。

   `getfattr --recursive --no-dereference --dump /path/to/mount/point`
3. ACL が大量に付与されているファイルが多数存在する。

   `getfacl --recursive /path/to/mount/point`
4. ファイルシステムが壊れている。

多くの場合は 1、稀に 4 はあるかと思いますが、2 と 3 は見たことありません。
ちなみに拡張属性と ACL は、少ない数とサイズであれば、inode 内に保存されます。(ファイルシステムの種類と inode サイズに依る。Linux なら XFS や ext4)

Answer (score -1):

ボリュームのマウントポイント(=計測ポイント)のディレクトリのサブディレクトリに別のボリュームをマウントしている場合、「`du`」の結果が「`df`」の結果を超える(ボリュームサイズを超える)ことがあると思います。

例えば、次のような場合、`du`の結果が`df`の結果を超えます。

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             50G   40G   10G  80% /var
/dev/sda4             20G   18G    2G  90% /var/log
```

- `df -h /var`は`50G`となる。(50GBのSize)
- `du -sh /var`は`58G`となる。(Usedの`40G`と`18G`の合計値)

Comment: 私もまずこのケースを疑いましたが、質問文の「想像した原因」2つ目でこちらのケースには該当しないと書かれています。